# Matrix vs. array environments

Tags: matrices, arrays

What is the difference between the `matrix` and `array` environments?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. `array` is a default environment of LaTeX available to any document class, whilst `matrix` come with `amsmath` package or AMS classes (`amsbook`, `amsart`)
2. The `matrix` environment mainly exist for naming consistency, because `amsmath` also provides several  environments for matrices with delimiters (e.g. `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `Bmatrix`, `vmatrix`, and  `Vmatrix`).
3. In  `matrix` there are not column specifications as `{ccc}`. By default, you can have up to ten centered columns (for another  alignment you must stay with  `array`). If you need more than ten columns you must modify the `MaxMatrixCols` counter.
4. `matrix` is  more economical with horizontal spacing (i.e., `array` is wider than `matrix`).

Answer (score 10):

I'll add that `mathtools` defines a series of starred `xmatrix*` environments (x=`p,b,B,v,V`), and the parallel `xsmallmatrix*` environments, which accept a *unique* optional argument, `[l]`, `[c]` or `[r]` for the set of columns, for the case where a different alignment is preferred, as in this example, borrowed from the mathtools documentation:

```
\[ \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
      -1 & 3 \\
       2 & -4
\end{pmatrix*} \]
```

[image]